# Jquery form loadPanelContent

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-plugins

I am scripting in admin template I got from Themeforest. I have been waiting on the author to help me with this question, but I am a bit unpatient.

What I am working with is what he calls content-panels, which is a jquery based "frameset" for lack of better words.

The author gave feedback to another customer below...

```
$('.content-panel').on('submit', 'form', function(event)
{
var form = $(this);

// Prevent default form submission
event.preventDefault();

// Load in content panel
form.loadPanelContent(this.action, {
type: this.method,
data: form.serialize()
});
});
```

This works great if my page or panel only has one form. The first form works great; it posts to the panel, inside the panel, but the second form gives me the %5Bobject%20HTMLInputElement%5D error.

In the snip above, .content-panel is the div wrapper. I have tried binding to the forms directly by both id and class, to no avail.

What I want is this...

```
<form id="form1" action="somelocation">
 To post to the panel
<form>

<form id="form2" action="somelocation">
 And this form to post to the same panel
<form>
```

Again, if you are not too familiar with loadPanelContent I dont think that part is the part to focus on as the snippet works for the first form but not on second one.

Hopefully I explained this correctly and hopefully someone can help.

Thanks a ton in advance.

Kenny

Comment: No one has any ideas?